# ViewController class with XIB not working in Sample.framework

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I have created sample.framework project with NSObject classes.
So its working fine in every project but when I m going to add ViewController class with .XIB in sample.framework and try to use same framework in any project, then it says

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'SampleViewController''

Please let us know that can i use ViewController class with XIB in sample.framework???

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Static library doesn't provide a bundle for resources, that's only the code. You'll need either to add shared xibs manually to the application target `Copy Bundle Resources` stage or you can use a single shared .bundle with all the resources; if latter you'll have to get the bundle first, then read the nibs from there:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mybundle" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle * bndl = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
NSArray *nibs = [bndl loadNibNamed:@"mynib.xib" owner:self options:nil];
```

or

```
[[Myviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"mynib.xib" bundle:bndl];
```

Don't forget to add the .bundle file to app's target `Copy Bundle Resources` stage if you decide to use bundles.